# Replacements for `target="_blank"`?

Tags: javascript, html, google-gadget

I am using `target="_blank"` in most of google gadgets so that the link opens in a new window, rather than in small gadget space, but it is polluting the browser with windows and I am looking for a solution so that the window would open to the current browsing window (like normal browsing without extra window clutter. Please, note that "without-target-blank" the link opens to the small gadget space (not the goal) but to open to the browsing space. Any way to do that without `target="_blank"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you're trying to work around the default Google Gadgets behavior?

Have you tried

```
target="_top"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Javascript like so to open in a new tab:

```
<a href="http://www.link.com" onclick="window.open(this.href); return false;">LINK</a>
```

Comment: This will open a new window, but it sounds like the OP wanted the link opened in the same window in the top frame (not the gadget's iframe).